# phpmyadmin and mysql socket error

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

once i try to connect to mysql on phpmyadmin in ubuntu i got this error

## 2002 - The server is not responding (or the local MySQL server's socket is not correctly configured)

but with mysql query browser i connect with out any error and it works

why phpmyadmin does not connect?

Answer (score 1):

The command line client uses a unix domain socket while PHPmsyqladmin uses a network socket.  You'll need to enable the network socket in the mysql config, most likely.

EDIT:

You can read about some of the troubleshooting (and windows) side of this:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html

And here is how to set up mysql to use a network config:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/mysql/switch-mysql-to-listen-on-tcp/